# Changing learning rate of keras sequential model sgd optimizer not having expected result

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Changing the learning rate of stochastic gradient descent optimizer for keras sequential model does not have the expected effect on the weights after training.

I have been trying to update the weights of a Keras sequential model based on an extremely small (4 samples and 3 features with binary labels) dataset after just one iteration over the whole dataset. Im doing this exercise because I am going to later manually perform backpropagation and show that my results match the computer. I am using the train_on_batch class to accomplish this. I want to emphasize the changes in weights after the one iteration done by train_on_batch but changing the learning rate does not seem to have a predictable effect on how big of a change the weights and biases experience. I tested what would happen if I set the learning rate to 0 and indeed I got an answer which makes no sense since the weights and biases should have just not changed. Shouldn't a change in learning rate be proportional to the changes in weight and bias values? Why are the weights changing even though I set the learning rate to zero?

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(2, input_shape=(3,), activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='ones', bias_initializer='zeros'), 
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='ones', bias_initializer='zeros')

])

sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0)

model.compile(
  optimizer='sgd',
  loss='mean_squared_error',
  metrics=['accuracy'],
)

model.train_on_batch(
  features, # training data
  labels, # training targets
)


for layer in model.layers:
    weights = layer.get_weights()[0]
    print(weights)

[[1.        1.       ]
 [1.        1.       ]
 [0.9999999 0.9999999]]
[[0.99839985]
 [0.99839985]]

for layer in model.layers:
    biases = layer.get_weights()[1]
    print(biases)

[-7.547273e-09 -7.547273e-09]
[-0.00160019]
```

Since weights are initialized at 1 and biases at zero, I would expect them to stay that way after I run train_on_batch since learn rate = 0. The fact that this is not the case reveals some underlying problem which I am not aware of.